# Quotient topology - can a non open set map back to open set?

Tags: general-topology

Say $X$ be a set in $\Bbb R^2$ defined by the disk: $x^2+y^2\le 1$ where $x,y \in \Bbb R$.

Now let's define a disjoint collection $X^*$ on $X$ by taking the boundary as one set - which is all $x,y$ s.t. $x^2+y^2=1$, and all other one point sets of the form $\{x \times y \}$ s.t. $x^2+y^2 \lt 1$. In other words take the entire boundary (circular) as one set, and all interior points as one point sets.

Now the book said that we can define a quotient map like this $p:X \to X^*$.

Let's denote the boundary set of $X$ in $X^*$ as $C$, means $C$ is the boundary of the disk $X$. so as $p^{-1}(C)$ is open, then $C$ is open as well. But how we can define $C$ in $\Bbb R^2$ as open set. Because $C$ is the boundary of the subspace $X$, and I can not find any open set $U$ in $\Bbb R^2$ s.t. $U\cap X$ is open and equals the boundary of $X$.

Then how can we call $C$ as open in $X^*$?

Comment: In order to answer your question we need the definition of $p$ which you do not give. I assume that if $(x,y) \in X \setminus C$ then $p(x,y)=\{(x,y)\}$ and if $(x,y) \in C$ then $p(x,y)=C$. In this case you remark correctly that $p^{-1}(\{C\}) = C$ which is not open in $X$, so $\{C\}$ cannot be open in $X^*$. Maybe the definition of $p$ is different?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a conceptual problem here. This is an instance of creating a new topological space out of the old ones. Let $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be the *closed unit disk*, i.e. $D:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$. The *boundary* $\partial D$ of $D$ is by definition $\overline{D}\cap\overline{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus D} $, which is nothing but the *unit sphere*, i.e. $\partial D=S^1:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2=1\}$.

Define a partition of $D$ as follows: $D/S^1:=\{\{(x,y)\}|(x,y)\in D^\circ\}\cup\partial D$. In other words, the boundary of the disk is one cell of the partition, while all the interior points are taken as singletons (point-by-point). Equivalently you could do this by defining an equivalence relation on $D$ (which I'll leave to you). Now we have a new set, namely $D/S^1$, and its elements (or points, if you may) are the subsets of $D$ we determined by the partition above.

Recall that our main goal was to create a new topological space. We have a new set, so all that's left is to define a topology on this new set. Let

$$\pi:D\to D/S^1,\pi(x,y):=\begin{cases}\{(x,y)\}&,\mbox{ if }(x,y)\in D^\circ\\ \partial D&,\mbox{ if }(x,y)\in\partial D\end{cases},$$

so that $\pi$ takes each point to the cell in the partition that contains it. $\pi$ is a somewhat natural function between the old set and the new set, and so we want a topology on the new set $D/S^1$ so that at least $\pi$ is continuous. Indeed, we shall define the topology $\tau_{D/S^1}$ on the new set as $\tau_{D/S^1}:=\{U\subset D/S^1|\pi^{-1}(U)\in \tau_D\}$. Of course there are other topologies we could put on the new set (e.g. indiscrete topology), but, again, the emphasis is on our motivation to relate the topology of the new space to the topology of the old one. $\tau_{D/S^1}$ is called the *quotient topology* (I'll leave the proof that this is indeed a topology on the new set to you). $\pi$ is trivially a *quotient map*, i.e. a map that is onto and continuous.

---

Here are the issues in your last paragraph:

- $\pi^{-1}(\{\partial D\})=\partial D=S^1$ is closed in $D$ (its complement is the unit open ball).
- Continuity (and the definition of the quotient topology) guarantees $U\subseteq D/S^1$ is open $\implies \pi^{-1}(U)\subseteq D$ is open, not the other way around.
- We don't define $\partial D$ as an open set, the topology of $D$ is already completely determined by the topology of the euclidean plane. Nor did we define $\pi(\partial D)=\{\partial D\}$ as an open set in the new space: indeed, we had done so, then by the definition of the quotient topology, $\pi^{-1}(\{\partial D\})=\partial D=S^1$ would have been open in $D$ too, which is not the case.

---

As a further exercise, show that $(D/S^1,\tau_{d/S^1})\cong (S^2,\epsilon|_{S^2})$, where $\epsilon|_{S^2})$ denotes the topology on the sphere induced by the euclidean topology in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Your projection maps the set $X$ to a set $X^* = \{ C, A \}$ of two elements *with the discrete topology*, i.e. all parts of $X^*$ are open *in $X^*$*. This means that in particular the singleton $\{ C\}$ is open (and closed!) in $X^*$, while the set $\{C\}$ is not open in $X$.

Comment: $A$ is not a single set, all interior points are individual sets in $X^*$. So there are inifinite number of sets in $X^*$